# php - get current variable name and put it as array key

Tags: php, arrays, var

I want to do something like this in php, dynamically:

```
$varname = $clang_arr['varname'];
```

and in loop, something like:

```
$a = [$x, $y, $z, $w, ...];
foreach($a as $v) $v = $clang_arr['v'];
```

And the result of the above will be:

```
$x = $clang_arr['x']
$y = $clang_arr['y']
...
```

I have tried somethings but unfortunately it didn't work!
Can i do something dynamically like this in php, or i can't?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to create dynamic variables?

Comment: Look into [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). Your `$a` array should contain variable names in that case. However, using dynamic variables is oftentimes considered a code smell. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: instead of  doing all this if you can properly elaborate what you are trying to achieve with proper input data as well as expected outcome. May be you will get a more suitable and quick answer.

Comment: @Jeto the problem i want to solve is: i have a language json file, i want to make all the keys in the json file a variables in php, something like... "json_key": "json_val"... $json_key = $clang_arr['json_key'] // and the result will be "json_val"..... i want to do this because i have made a system, almost finished and the language labels is by php variables, and now i have made an update and all the language labels is in json file, so i want to make this instead of edit the whole system.... i hope you understand what i really want to do

Comment: If you are relying on variable names for your application to work time to think about refactoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function you're looking for is [`extract`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php). Simple example:

```
$arr = ['x' => 1, 'y' => 2];
extract($arr);
var_dump($x, $y);
// outputs
// int(1)
// int(2)
```

Comment: THANK YOU, THATS REALLY WHAT I WANT.. THANKS ALOT

Comment: But I still don't understand what's the problem with `$arr['x']`?

Comment: you can check the comments on the main question... my comment, forth comment, to know what problem i want to solve